# Virtual property with private set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to use fluent nhibernate in a MVC project... i am very new to nhibernate and fluent... It seems the entities should have properties that are virtual and the set should be private for IDs... i use vb language...so tried using overrideable...it gives an error...

```
Public Overridable Property DesignId() As Integer
    Get

    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As Integer)

    End Set
End Property
```

it says property cannot be overrideable because it has a private accessor...have no idea how to go about...all tutorials in the net are in c#... my client specifically in vb....thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making the setter protected, so that the overriding classes can see it...

I.e.:

```
Private _designId as Integer
Public Overridable Property DesignId() As Integer
    Get
        Return _designId
    End Get
    Protected Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _designId = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to VB, if you make the setter protected, that should avoid giving you the error (since Protected allows you to override the setting).

Answer (score 0):

Use Protected instead of Private. It's OK to use Public, too, if that OK with your design - Set is not necessary to be Private, that's just good design.

The Private error is VB limitation, this works in C#. VB requires to override both getter and setter, while C# does not.